# Initializer from protocol conformance in extension

Tags: ios, swift

I'm adding some functionality to a bunch of objects in my app, and to ensure every class is compliant, I wanted to create a protocol that defines the requirements by the feature.

```swift
protocol Shrinkable {
    var name: String { get }
    func makeEnlargedVersion() -> EnlargedObject
}
```

That all works fine, but now I want to add an `init` to the protocol which takes an `EnlargedObject` and creates a new object. This would work regularly, but for tidy-sake I want to have the protocol conformance in an extension.
feature.

```swift
protocol Shrinkable {
    var name: String { get }
    func makeEnlargedVersion() -> EnlargedObject
    init(enlargedObject: EnlargedObject)
}
```

```swift
class WaterBottle {
    var size: Int
}

extension WaterBottle: Shrinkable {

   var name: String {
        return "Spring Water"
   }
   
    required init(enlargedObject: EnlargedObject) {
        
    }
}
```

This presents an error, as required initialiser can not be in an extension.

`'required' initializer must be declared directly in class 'TestObject' (not in an extension)`

Is there a way around this? I would like for all protocol conformance code to be inside an extension.

Comment: You can't - as the error says.  A protocol initialiser is a required initialiser and therefore must be in the class

Comment: That I can see, I was wondering if there was another way

Comment: No.  It is one of the language rules.

Comment: What about having an abstract base class for the `init`?

Comment: You can change the init to a function that return an object that's conformed to `Shrinkable ` from `EnlargedObject ` I think?

Comment: @HangarRash Swift doesn’t have abstract classes.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I meant a class that acts as an abstract class. Like `UIActivity`, for example.